# Add folder to classpath for properties file Scala

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.0

I am using a java jar dependency that requires a certain property file to be on the classpath.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to add this folder/file to the classpath.  I am using play 2.0.

I have added the config.properties file to both the /conf directory and have tried to add it to the root of my app source folder.  The file does not seem to be recognized by the dependency.

BTW: play 2.0 uses sbt to compile and run the application so maybe something there could help?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine if you put the property file where your class files are. When you use SBT you probably use either:

The project root directory as source directory. In this case just put your property file into the root directory.

Or the maven layout, so your normal classes are under src/main/scala In this case put your property file under src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer of Jens Schauder should solve your issue, you may want to try to add the file to the *lib* folder.

Play 2.0 won't remove files manually added in there (at least it doesn't at the time I'm writting this!) and that folder should be included into the classpath automatically.